# C functions definition

Tags: c, function

Recently I was studying the book The C Programming Language and in the first chapter I came across this paragraph

> Function definitions can appear in any order, and in one source file or several,
> although no function can be split between files.  If the source program appears
> in several files, you may have to say more to compile and load it than if it all
> appears in one, but that is an operating system matter, not a language attribute.

I have understood the part where it is saying that order of function within program does not matter. Can anyone explain the rest of it?

Comment: It just means that *separate compilation* is possible. You can split your program in many source files (the language wording is *compilation unit*). This is very useful for large programs and allows to reuse code and optionaly store parts in libraries that are easy to use (*link*) into other programs.

Comment: Please note that this book was written in the pre function prototype declaration era. The attempt to update it to 1989's version of C could have done with more effort. Consequently you might find a lot of very outdated statements and coding styles. When learning how to do programming in the year 2021, I don't recommend reading 40 year old books.

Comment: When asking about text in books, or citing text in books generally, include a bibliographic citation, including at least the title, author(s), edition number, and location information inside the book, such as page number or chapter, section, and/or clause numbers, or both. This enables other people to look up the passage and see its context.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard only dictates that a conforming implementation shall allow for separated compilation (several files). However, exactly how to compile and link is outside the scope of the language specification and depends on the actual implementation. For example, MSVC may require very different arguments from GCC while both are conforming implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that the C standard does not care about compiler and linker details.

So the C standard doesn't care about how you load libraries or how you use Makefiles or any of the other details of writing a non trivial program in C.

That is mainly due to the fact that C is often used with custom toolchains for embedded systems programming.